# Bluemix for iOS8 Getting Started instructions - missing IMFClient

Tags: ios8, ibm-cloud

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html

Following instruction in the Getting Started docs for a new iOS8 application in Bluemix, I get a compilation error for the lines

IMFClient *imfClient = [IMFClient sharedInstance];
[imfClient initializeWithBackendRout ....

to throw errors.

AppDelegate.m:27:29: Use of undeclared identifier 'IMFClient'
AppDelegate.m:28:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'imfClient'

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for enabling an existing project I found that the '#import ' statement was missing from the documentation, this needs to added in your AppDelegate.m file to resolve the compilation error.